# AliExpress API: Receive the title of the product category

Tags: aliexpress

I use AliExpress API for dropshipping (it's important). When I send a request to receive the list of products (using aliexpress.ds.recommend.feed.get endpoint), AliExpress API returns products with the first and the second level category (id and title of categories).
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANHyv.png)

But when I send a request to receive product details (using aliexpress.ds.product.get endpoint), API returns only the product category (without title).
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM9LX.png)

AliExpress also has an endpoint to receive the list of categories (aliexpress.ds.category.get), but this returns only the first and second levels of categories.

So, I can't get the product category title. Maybe, I missed something, but I didn't find more details in the documentation.